# Unicode decode error report in Spyder

Tags: python, unicode, spyder

I'm really a new hand to python. I come up with a question about Spyder. 
the situation is:

(1). I wrote a very simple script (that is " print "good" " if you'd like to know), and save it as a .py file with Chinese characters in the file name. I ran this script in Spyder, it worked normally and printed the correct result in console window.

(2). then I deliberately made a syntaxerror (that is: prit "good") and ran it again, it didin't work of course, however, the console window didin't report the syntaxerror while the Internal console window reported a UnicodeDecodeError, something like "`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb4 in position 39: invalid start byte`".

(3). then I tried this syntax nonsense file in IDLE, it reported the syntaxerror as expected. Nothing was mentiond about the UnicodeDecodeError

What I want to ask is that is there really a "UnicodeDecodeError" as presented in (2)? Why didn't it appear when the script is fine or runned in IDLE as I described in (1)and(3)? what actually happend here?

here is the entire error about the UnicodeDecodeError in the internal console：

> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\pythonshell.py", line 566, in write_error
> > >           self.shell.write_error(self.get_stderr())
> > >         File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\baseshell.py", line 272, in get_stderr
> > >           return self.transcode(qba)
> > >         File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\baseshell.py", line 258, in transcode
> > >           return to_text_string(qba.data(), 'utf8')
> > >         File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\py3compat.py", line 134, in to_text_string
> > >           return unicode(obj, encoding)
> > >         File "D:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
> > >           return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
> > >       UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb2 in position 39: invalid start byte

Comment: (*Spyder developer here*) What Spyder version are you using?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba it's 2.3.2

Comment: I thought we had fixed all Unicode errors in that release :-) This seems to be another bug in Spyder code, so don't worry about it. I'll see if I can fix it for our next release. I opened [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/detail?id=2108) to not forget about it.

Comment: Another thing: it'd be great if you could post here the entire error you're seeing in the internal console. That could help me to locate the problem more easily, Thanks :-)

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Ok, I've added the entire error message into the question.

Comment: Thanks! It's a simple fix, it'll be released in 2.3.3